# How to express "move the wheel" left or right in one word?

Tags: phrases, word-in-context

Specifically, I want to know if this phrase is correct, it's a piece of advice to pass the driver license test:
"From my point of view, you should go more slower than faster, so, you have time to steer under the examiner's instructions".

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Steer seems fine. Also "turn" should work. You might consider saying "so you have time to steer when the examiner says so".

Comment: more slow = slower ---- more slower is not correct.

Comment: *Steer* means *move the steering wheel to the left or right*, so I'm not sure how the title of your question relates to the body.

Comment: Regarding "move the wheel”, I would use "turn the wheel".

Comment: Note that (unless you take both hands off the wheel) you are [*steering*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/steer?s=t) the entire time that the car is moving, *including when driving along a straight road without turning the wheel.*

Comment: Thank you, I should take care of the combinations like more -er... I knew the rule but I made the mistake anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking apart your sentence

> From my point of view

is fine

> you should go more slower than faster

is incorrect, as natives we are taught not to use "more" with "-er", more correct might be

> you should drive slower *rather* than faster
>   you should drive more slowly than fast
>   you should drive more slowly

"drive" might be a better choice than the informal "go"

> so, you *will* have time to steer *the car*

as pointed out, "steering" is to move the car to the left, right or straight ahead

> under the examiner's instructions.
>   under the examiner's directions.

is fine.

Regarding your one word for "moving the wheel left or right", one

> **turns** the *(steering)* wheel

in order to steer the car left or right.

Comment: Good answer. An extra note for the OP: "From my point of view" is a common expression, but when giving advice I prefer "In my opinion". Or perhaps "I suggest that you drive slower..."

Comment: @nnnnnn +1 "In my opinion, I would suggest that you *(should)* drive..."